# Cleanest way to create an object from JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class (not active record) and I would like to create objects from API data.

Since fields name/structure don't match, I don't think that it's possible to use `params` as we would use with forms.

That's why I'm mapping the attributes as follow:

```
job = Job.new()

job.id = attributes['id']
job.title = attributes['fields']['title']
job.body = attributes['fields']['body-html']
job.how_to_apply = attributes['fields']['how_to_apply-html'].presence
attributes['fields']['city'].each { |city| job.cities << city['name'] } if attributes['fields']['city']
attributes['fields']['country'].each { |country| job.countries << country['name'] }
job.start_date = Date.parse(attributes['fields']['date']['created'])
job.end_date = Date.parse(attributes['fields']['date']['closing'])
attributes['fields']['source'].each { |source| job.sources << source['name'] }
attributes['fields']['categories'].each { |category| job.categories << category['name'] }

job
```

`attributes` is the  `data`  part of a JSON response.

What do you guys think?

Comment: When the names do not match then you will need to define the mapping somewhere. I would probably create a `Job.from_json` method. But that doesn't really change the verbosity of the mapping method. And where to do the mapping is certainly opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable way is to have an initializer in `Job` and call it like this:

```rb
job = Job.new(
  id: attributes['id'],
  title: attributes['fields']['title'],
  body: attributes['fields']['body-html'],
  how_to_apply: attributes['fields']['how_to_apply-html'].presence,
  cities: attributes['fields']['city']&.map { |city| city['name'] },
  countries: attributes['fields']['country'].map { |country| country['name'] },
  start_date: Date.parse(attributes['fields']['date']['created']),
  end_date: Date.parse(attributes['fields']['date']['closing']),
  sources: attributes['fields']['source'].map { |source| source['name'] },
  categories: attributes['fields']['categories'].map { |category| category['name'] }
)
```

initializer can take named parameters or just a options hash (not recommended):

```rb
class Job < ...
  def initializer(id:, title:, cities: nil, and_so_on__:)
    self.id = id
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I would really just have the intializer take hash input 1:1 and use a factory method/apapter to create the instance from JSON. Otherwise you have to provide that wonky JSON input everywhere like in your tests.

Comment: I also don't think this is a case where using required keyword attributes is that suitible. When dealing with user input (or input in general) its usually better if your code does not error out at the first missing attribute so that you can use something like validations to provide better feedback to the client/user about whats missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.tap` method, its a little bit cleaner this way. Also some things can be moved to methods, for example:

```
fields = attributes['fields']

job = Job.new.tap do |j|
  j.id = attributes['id']
  j.title = fields['title']
  j.body = fields['body-html']
  j.how_to_apply = fields['how_to_apply-html'].presence
  j.start_date = date_parser(fields['date']['created'])
  j.end_date = date_parser(fields['date']['closing'])
  j.countries = fields['country'].map { |country| country['name'] }
  j.cities = fields['city']&.map { |city| city['name'] }

  (...)
end

def date_parser(date)
  Date.parse(date)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged Rails you can use `ActiveModel::Model` and `ActiveModel::Attributes` to create a rich model with typecasting, validations etc.

Then just create a factory method to create model instances from raw JSON:

```
class Job
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :id, :integer
  attribute :title, :string
  attribute :body, :string
  attribute :how_to_apply, :string
  attribute :start_date, :date
  attribute :end_date, :date
  # Unfortunately ActiveModel::Attributes does not support array attributes
  attr_accessor :city
  attr_accessor :country
  attr_accessor :source
  attr_accessor :categories

  def self.from_json(**attributes)
    # use attributes.fetch('fields') instead if you
    # want to raise and halt execution
    fields = attributes['fields'] 
    new(attributes.slice('id', 'title')) do |job|
      job.assign_attributes(
        body: fields['body-html'],
        how_to_apply: fields['how_to_apply-html'],
        city: fields['city']&.map {|c| c['name'] },
        country: fields['country']&.map {|c| c['name'] },
        start_date: fields.dig('date', 'created'),
        end_date: fields.dig('date', 'closing'),
        source: fields['source']&.map {|s| s['name'] },
        categories: fields['categories']&.map {|c| c['name'] }
      ) if fields
    end
  end
end
```

If this method glows to an unruly size or if the complexity increases you can use the adapter pattern or a serializer.

> Since fields name/structure don't match, I don't think that it's possible to use params as we would use with forms.

This is not quite true. [ActionController::Parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) is really just a Hash like object and you can use `.merge` to manipulate it just like a hash:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(json_hash)
                                     .permit(:id, :title, fields: {})
params .slice(:id, :title).merge(
   how_to_apply: params[:fields]['how_to_apply-html'],
   # ...
)
```